# Using external library classes in client side :GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I want to use Solrj library in my GWT application. I made a GWT server class to communicate with Solrj client. My client code gets a `Collection<FacetField>` from the server class and builds the UI.

My problem is that GWT complains about missing source code:

```
No source code is available for type org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.FacetField; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I can create an additional module for Solrj and then GWT will compile it to JS. But it will compile a lot of other classes, that I might never use on the client.

Another way is to write some wrappers of Solr classes and pass them to the client. But I'm not sure, because these wrappers will import Solr classes and I might have the same problem again.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: You're trying to use SolrJ *from the client side*? Why are you wanting to do this instead of using the usual GWT-RPC?

Comment: No, no. I use RPC to call server class, which itself calls Solrj library. It's just that client gets `Collection<FacetField>` and complains

Comment: Yes wrappers would not help. You have to use source code. But you might have another problem, is FacetField serializable by GWT rules? I would follow @suresh advice

Comment: That is what (written in answer) we are doing right now, not with Solrj, but with some other third party lib.

Comment: I've read also about RequestFactory. It seems to me, that it allows to write less code and just map a Solrj object to my proxy object. But Solrj object is not persisted and I don't think it has an id at all. Would it be possible to use RequestFactory in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write some `DataLorry`(dummy object)

```
server|| FacetField obj==>DataLorry obj==> client.
```

Flush required data in to `DataLorry`  object.

That saves you a lot of data traffic between client and server even, since you are passing only required data on the wire.

Make sure that object is `serializable` and in `shared` package.

Comment: So this dummy class shouldn't be a wrapper over FacetField and shouldn't know anything about FacetField class, is it correct?

Comment: @damluar Yup. You need to pass the required data from `FacetField` to your Dummy object. So that I'l become independent.

Comment: ok, I got it. If no other answer will be proposed soon, I will accept your answer. Thanks!